# Plot several Y-values at the same x-value in .NET

Tags: c#, winforms, plot

The following plot was created with MATLAB. I want to have the excact same plot in windows forms.

[image]

However, it does not work out to plot several y-values to one x-value (in this case: 0).

**My code**

```
this.chart3.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
this.chart3.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, doubleValueArray); //length is 1600
this.chart3.Update();
```

but I get the error

```
Exception was thrown: Series data points do not support values of type 
System.Double[] only values of these types can be used: Double, Decimal,   
Single, int, long, uint, ulong, String, DateTime, short, ushort.
```

...what I do not understand, because based on the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487988(v=vs.110).aspx) the second parameter of the AddXY accepts an double array.

Do I need to setup something else e.g. in the properties?

Thanks for any help

Comment: The y-values are accepted as arrays only for a few charttypes like BoxPlot. for point of line type you need one x-and one y-value per data point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two arrays for the `AddXY` function:

```
this.chart3.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(xArray, yArray);
```

In xArray there a the x-values of the single data points. So in your case it should be an array with 1600 zeros.

UPDATE:

You have to add

```
this.chart3.Series["Series1"].CustomProperties = "IsXAxisQuantitative=True";
```

otherwise it will not work on the x=0 axis

I formulated the problem on that axis in an own question: [Plotting two y-values for x=0 in a MS Chart control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786931/plotting-two-y-values-for-x-0-in-a-ms-chart-control)