# Add Multi-Dimensional Y Values for Series in for .NET Chart Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, charts, data-visualization

In .NET Charting namespace, The `Series` class has following `AddXY` overload for its `DataPointCollection` member:

```
  public int AddXY(object xValue, params object[] yValue)
```

Which means in case some `SeriesChartType` require more than one value of Y for each X value, I can put:

```
  my_series.Points.AddXY(x, y_1, y_2, y_3);
```

where `x` and `y_1 y_2 y_3` are double, and it's okay since the `params` keyword

But right now I have a function which receives a certain type of series and a `double[]` y values like this:

```
private void add_a_pair(double x, double[] ys, SeriesChartType type)
{
    my_series.ChartType = type;
    my_series.addXY(x, ys);
}
```

the compiler will throw exception saying:

> Series data points do not support values of type
>   **System.Double[]**,  only values of these types can be used: Double,
>   Decimal, Single, int, long, uint, ulong, String, DateTime, short,
>   ushort.

which is a bit confusing since one of the overload clearly defines it can take the `object[]` (which I suppose `double[]` will be compatible down with). I found out [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783596/plot-several-y-values-at-the-same-x-value-in-net) encountered the same thing but the motivation and answer is not what I want.

The only workaround I'm think it might work is sth like this:

```
if(type.Equals(SeriesChartType.ErrorBar))
{
    my_series.AddXY(x, ys[0], ys[1], ys[2]);
}
if(....)
{
    my_series.AddXY(x, ys[0], ys[1]);
}
....
```

which looks pretty stupid. Is something basic about C# I'm missing?

**【SOLUTION】** See TaW's comments.

Comment: While the linked post is mainly about databinding you can find the solution in option 2. The trick is to use the `Add()` overload instead of `AddXY()`..! `   my_series.add.Add(new DataPoint( x, ys));`

Comment: @TaW yes it works. Many thanks!